# Duplicate results in a view despite using DISTINCT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a bit of trouble with this particular SQL query
I'm creating a view that shows for each type of user, the amount
of problems they reported, the oldest date in which a problem was solved, 
and the oldest date in which a problem is still unsolved
It's the first part it's not working as i'm needing it. Despite
using the DISTINCT clause, the query returns something like this

Admin, 0, 08/21/1995, 03/05/1991
Admin, 14, 08/21/1995, 03/05/1991

and so on, for the rest of user types.
Is there a way to filter those results so that the columns with a 0 value 
do not come up as a result?, or the behaviour has to do with the way i'm 
making the query?

The view code is this:

```
select distinct u.user_cod_type,
(select count(p.problem_id)
from problems p
        where u.user_id = p.user_id) as problemquantity, 
(select min(problem_solved_date)
from problems p1, problem_history h
        where p1.problem_id=h.problem_id
and problem_solved_date is not null) as solvedolderdate, 
(select min(problem_date)
         from problems p2, problem_history h1
        where p2.problem_id=h1.problem_id
    and problem_solved_date is null) as unsolvedolderdate
 from users u
```

Tables schema:

```
problems
(
  problem_id      integer  not null identity(1,1)
  equipment_id    integer  not null,
  user_id         integer  not null,
  problem_date    datetime not null,
  problem_descrip varchar(255)
)

users
(user_id             integer identity (1,1) not null,
user_cod_type         char(20)     not null,
userfname             varchar(80),
userlname             varchar(80),
usermail              varchar(80),
useraddress           varchar(255)
)

problem_history
(problem_history_id integer identity (1,1) not null,
problem_priority char(20) not null,
problem_id integer not null,
problem_status_code char(20) not null,
problem_personnel_id integer not null,
problem_solved_date datetime)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query, reformatted and using explicit joins:

```
select distinct u.user_cod_type,
       (select count(p.problem_id)
        from problems p
        where u.user_id = p.user_id
       ) as problemquantity,
       (select min(problem_solved_date)
        from problems p1 join
             problem_history h
             on p1.problem_id=h.problem_id and
                problem_solved_date is not null
       ) as solvedolderdate,
       (select min(problem_date)
        from problems p2 join
             problem_history h1
             on p2.problem_id=h1.problem_id and problem_solved_date is null
       ) as unsolvedolderdate
 from users u;
```

This is what is causing your duplicates:

```
select distinct u.user_cod_type,
       (select count(p.problem_id)
        from problems p
        where u.user_id = p.user_id
--------------^
       ) as problemquantity,
```

You are looking for distinct codes, but the correlation is by `user_id`.  Presumably, multiple users have the same code.  Hence, you are getting a separate row for each user.  One solution is to use a subquery.  It would have the form:

```
select u.user_code_type, sum(problemquantity) as problemquantity,
       min(solvedolderdate) as solvedolderdate,
       min(unsolvedolderdate) as unsolvedolderdate
from (select u.user_code_type, u.user_id,
             . . . <-- rest of your query here
     ) t
group by u.user_code_type
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gordon. There's one thing i do not follow.. when you say rest of your query, you mean that the select count and both select min can go in that subquery as they were in my original query?

Comment: @JoseIgnacioRadesca . . . Yes.  What I mean is remove the `distinct` from your query.  Make it a subquery.  Then do explicit aggregation with `group by on the outside.